# How do I preserve inter-string null characters in std::format string

Tags: c++, c++20, format-string, stdformat

In an attempt to refactor this code:

```cpp
static const auto opf_str = [&]() {
    std::string result;
    for(auto& e : extension_list) {
        result.append(StringUtils::ToUpperCase(e.substr(1)) + " file (*"s + e + ")\0*"s + e + "\0"s);
    }
    result += "All Files (*.*)\0*.*\0\0"s;
    return result;
}();
```

I replaced the `std::string::operator+` joins with `std::format`:

```cpp
static const auto opf_str = [&]() {
    std::string result;
    for(auto e : extension_list) {
        result.append(std::format("{0} file (*{1})\0*{1}\0", StringUtils::ToUpperCase(e.substr(1)), e));
    }
    result += "All Files (*.*)\0*.*\0\0"s;
    return result;
}();
```

But the internal null characters (which are required for how [`OPENFILENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamea) works) are being stripped in the `std::format` version.

Changing the format string to an actual `std::string` causes a compiler error because the string isn't a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string` as argument doesn't work, but at least `std::string_view` should be fine. There is no issue with having it even as the result of a constant expression if it is referencing only static objects:

```
std::format("{0} file (*{1})\0*{1}\0"sv, StringUtils::ToUpperCase(e.substr(1)), e)
```

---

Looking a the current draft specification of `std::basic_format_string` it is indeed impossible to use a `std::string` as format string to `std::format`, even if its construction is a constant expression. As an alternative it is of course always possible to use `std::vformat` instead, which doesn't perform the compile-time checks. (It is in the end not really surprising since the `consteval` construction of the `std::basic_format_string` would need to copy the string contents, but can't rely on storing the result in dynamic memory.)

Comment: `sv` string_view literal works. I really should remember that string_view is a thing...the literal operators more-so.